# How to give give link to filtered items so that they link to different websites?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make my filtered items a link so that it would connect to different websites but I do not know how to do it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SearchBarStyle.css"

const SearchBar = () => {

    const waterInfo = [
        {title: "About Water", link:"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water"},
        {title: "Water (Molecule)", link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water"},
        {title: "Water (Chemistry)", link: "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Water"}
    ]

    const [input, setInput] = useState("")

    const HandleInput = (event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value)
    }

    const DeleteInput = () => {
        setInput("")
    }

    const filterItems = waterInfo.filter((wI) => { 
        return wI.title.includes(input)
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <h2 className="search-anything-header">Search anything about water!</h2>
            <div className="inputs-holder">
                <input type={"text"} value={input} onChange={HandleInput} placeholder="About Water?" className="searchbar"/>
                <button onClick={DeleteInput} className="delete-button"><b>✖</b></button>

            </div>
            <ul className="results">
                {filterItems.map((wI) => {
                    return <li><a href=""target="_blank">{wI.title}</a></li>
                
                })}
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

So when I map the array, I want to link the title and link in waterInfo array so that when you click onto the title, it transfers user to the link.

Comment: Have you tried this: `href={wI.link}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution. Just add `{wI.link}` to `href`

```
<ul className="results">
    {filterItems.map((wI, i) => {
      return (
        <li>
          <a href={wI.link} target="_blank">
            {wI.title}
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
```

Comment: You should remove the quotes around `{wI.link}`